# bash check vowels with regular expression

Tags: regex, bash, grep

How do I check if the first letter in each word in a text file has no vowel (aeiou) using regular expression. I have tried this

```
grep [!^"aeiou"] file.txt
```

It works a little, but it highlights vowels, not the first letter which are not vowel.

Comment: Is `pseudo-code` one word or 2? How about `we're`? Provide sample input and expected output and include the cases that you can imagine would be difficult to write a script to get right.

Comment: A tip for future coding in bash: If you want some string to be passed entirely to the command (`grep` in this case), without being parsed by `bash` first, quote entire string in single quotes. So your grep line should have looked as : `grep '[^aeiou]' file.txt` Currently, `[]` will be processed by `bash` first, as they are file matching wild-characters for `bash`..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a lookbehind based regex to highlight  the first letter in each  word which must not be a vowel.

```
grep -Pi '(?<!\S)[^aeiou]' file
```

Comment: This so only mark the first non vowel letter, in word like `the` it marks  `th` and in `cruise` it marks `cr`. I am not saying that this is a problem.

Comment: @Jotne what do you mean by the above, it correctly highlights `t` in `the` and `c` in `cruise`

Comment: Un my ubuntu I get `th` in red color in the word  `the` I would expect only the first letter  `t` to be in red.  If I test this `echo "tea the" | grep -Pi '(?<!\S)[^aeiou]'` I get three letters in color red. `t` in  `tea` and `th` in `the`

Comment: @Jotne weired thing it works perfectly for me. Which version of Ubuntu are you running?.  `(?<!\S)` is an assertion which asserts that the match must not  be preceded by a non-space character. And the following `[^aeiou]` matches only a single character. So this would highlight  `t` in the and tea.

Comment: Hmm.  14.10 (Gnu grep 2.20) gives errors.  12.04.5 (Gnu grep 2.10) OK. 14.04.2 (Gnu grep 2.16) OK

Comment: seems like a bug in version 2.20.

Comment: @ScottPearce If you see my post, it does work fine, but mark some extra letters if you are using `gnu grep 2.20`

Comment: I actually don't see a difference between your command output and the solution Avinash provided! They both works the same! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an `awk` that mark first letter in the word wit color red if its not a vowel.

```
awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {s=substr($i,1,1);if (tolower(s)~/[^aeiou]/) $i="\033[1;31m"s"\033[0m"substr($i,2)}}1' file
```